# Invalid destination position for blit error

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I got this error. This is the full traceback.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/hobin/PycharmProjects/codeitPython/Snake_game.py", line 103, in <module>
> snakegame()
> File "C:/Users/hobin/PycharmProjects/codeitPython/Snake_game.py", line 52, in snakegame
> dis.blit(value, round(display_width / 3), round(display_height / 5))
> TypeError: invalid destination position for blit
> ```

Here's the code that related the error

```
while not game_over:
    while game_end == True:
        #For displaying the score
        score = Length_of_snake -1
        score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)
        value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, greencolor)
        dis.blit(value, round(display_width / 3), round(display_height / 5))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True # The game window is still open
                game_end = False # game has been ended
```

I don't have any clue... what should I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd argument (*dest*) of [`pygame.Surfac.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) has be pair of coordinates. Either a tuple with 2 components or a list with 2 elements:

<s>`dis.blit(value, round(display_width / 3), round(display_height / 5))`</s>

```py
dis.blit(value, ( round(display_width / 3), round(display_height / 5) ) )
```

For the sake of completeness it has to be mentioned that the argument can also be a rectangle. A tuple with the 4 components (left, top, width, height).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I can be done because of your answer.